# Making inputs dependent in Shiny with default values

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple web app with 2 sets of inputs:

- A drop-down of distribution names
- Text inputs for parameters corresponding to the selected distribution

I want the labels for the parameters to correspond to the selected distribution. I have got this working, but I get a warning when I first load the page, seemingly due to the default selected value from the drop-down not having registered quickly.

The warning I get is:

```
Warning: Error in [[: attempt to select less than one element in get1index
Stack trace (innermost first):
    84: %AND%
    83: tag
    82: tags$div
    81: div
    80: textInput
    79: renderUI [H:\Repos\DiscreteEventSimulation\debugdefaultdrop/app.R#34]
    78: func
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$selparams
     1: runApp
```

Here's a MWE:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("seldist"),
    uiOutput("selparams")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    DISTS <- list("Normal"=list(params=c("mean", "variance"),
                                short="N"),
                  "Weibull"=list(params=c("scale", "shape"),
                               short="Wei"),
                  "Uniform"=list(params=c("lower", "upper"),
                               short="U"),
                  "Log-Normal"=list(params=c("location", "scale"),
                                  short="logN")
                  )

    output$seldist <- renderUI({
        selectInput("seldist", "Distribution", choices=names(DISTS), selected="Normal")
    })

    output$selparams <- renderUI({
        item_list <- list()
        item_list[[1]] <- textInput("param1", DISTS[[input$seldist]]$params[1], "")
        item_list[[2]] <- textInput("param2", DISTS[[input$seldist]]$params[2], "")
        do.call(tagList, item_list)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can enclose the code inside second renderUI in a `if(!is.null(input$seldist)){...}` block

Comment: That was easy, thanks. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it accepted.